# Why is it not obvious to Bobby Long?

Tags: plot-explanation, love-song-for-bobby-long

In  the 2004 movie *Love Song for Bobby Long*

**Why does it not occur to Bobby sooner, that Pursy is his daughter?**

Pursy says something like, "did you not count out the nine months?" and although Bobby is quite the drunkard, he was a former University Prof and not so dim-witted. So, how could he have missed something as obvious as the girl of his former lover presenting herself and not even think it was his own girl? Did he know and just not let on? He seems legitimately surprised after she makes the discovery and reveals it to him.